# How to do a Boolean if statement with strings?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, nameerror

I have a chunk of code that goes like:

```
maybeYes = input("Please enter Yes to start.")
if maybeYes == "Yes":
    pass
else:
    print "Wrong answer."
```

It gives the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Yes' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `raw_input()` in place of `input()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is python, use raw_input instead of input.
Input is considered dangerous, because it evaluates whatever you input, so if you do:

```
   x = input()
```

and enter 2+4, x will be equal to 6. raw_input just gives you the entered string.

Comment: Thanks jrdn that worked. One other question. If I want this function (because this is in a user defined function) to run again if the condition is False, how to I make it do that? Right now it just prints Wrong Answer and moves right along.

Comment: Instead of running the function again, it's probably easiest to put your code inside a while loop, like while raw_input() != "Yes": print "try again"

Comment: But the condition won't change so it's infinitely print "try again" with no way to stop it.

Comment: Give it a try :) The loop condition is reevaluated each time through.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I set the input equal to a variable and the input can't change if it's constantly printing "try again".

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. Do it the way i said in my comment, with the input in the loop condition.

Comment: I did that. In your example if I enter No it keeps printing "try again" in an infinite loop because the input isn't changing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

```
>>> maybeYes = raw_input("Please enter Yes to start ")
Please enter Yes to start yes
>>> maybeYes
'yes'
```

Think of `input()` as if you was to type directly into the interpreter, so `yes` would need to be `'yes'` for python to known you mean the string `yes`.

**Edit:**

You need to use `while` to loop.

```
while raw_input("Please enter Yes to start: ") != 'Yes':
       print 'Wrong'

print 'Correct'

print 'Doing something else...'

#Carry on here
```

Output:

```
Please enter Yes to start: nowg
Wrong
Please enter Yes to start: wggwe
Wrong
Please enter Yes to start: Yes
Correct
Doing something else...
```

Comment: So what if I want it to loop and say "Wrong answer every time the input isn't Yes and only move on if it is?

Comment: I don't you guys understand what I'm trying to do. The input isn't changing so how can the loop stop. I want it to ask for input again if the input wasn't Yes the first time. I don't want an infinitely repeating string of print statements.

Comment: Can't, not enough reputation.

Comment: You will get reputation for accepting the answer, you have to click tick.

Answer (score 0):

This version will accept any variation of "Yes", so "yes", "YES", "YeS", "yES", etc.

```
answer = raw_input('Please enter Yes to start: ')
while answer.upper() != 'YES':
   print 'Sorry, your entered something else'
   answer = raw_input('Please enter Yes to start: ')
print "Thank you, you entered ", answer
```

Comment: This is a bit over-complicated, you can call `upper` from `raw_input()` i.e `while raw_input("Please enter Yes to start: ").upper() != 'YES':`